# Is there a way to declare a class header in the same way a function header can be declared?

Tags: visual-c++

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class Colour
{
private:
    int _r, _g, _b;
public:
    Colour(int r = 0, int g = 0, int b = 0) : _r(r), _g(g), _b(b) {}
};
class Purevirtual
{
public:
    virtual int f(int x)  = 0;
    virtual void setColour(const Colour &c) = 0;
};

class Inherit : public Purevirtual
{
private :
    Colour _c;
public:
    Inherit(const Colour &c) : _c(c)
    {}
    int f(int x) override
    {
        return 2*x;
    }
    void setColour(const Colour &colour) override
    {
        _c = colour;
    }
};
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

If I put the class Colour after Purevirtual at compile time it will generate an error. I don't know why. A solution is to create and include in the main file the header with the class Colour but for me, it seems it will complicate the code.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler starts compiling at the top and finish at the end of the file, so if you define something after you use it, the compiler will said it is not defined. You can forward-declare the class, without class body and after, define the class. Something like this:

```
class Colour;

class PureVirtual
{
 .... the purevirtual body class doing reference to Colour class ....
};

class Colour
{
 .... the colour body class ...
}
```